# How to mention the localhost in android

Tags: android

I am trying to call the localhost in my android application. But unfortunately it is not possible i used several methods like emulator local host

`http://10.0.2.2/android/dbconnection.php`

and then my network ip address

`http://192.168.1.xx/android/dbconnection.php`

also

```
http://localhost:8080/android/dbconnection.php
```

but nothing is connected to my localhost. For this purpose i refer some stackoverflow answers that is also not working

Comment: You are trying to use a local DB? why not SQLite?

Comment: Are you testing this from an emulator or a device? What port number is your Web server listening on? Is the Web server itself set up to listen to `localhost` (i.e., does this work on a desktop browser)?

Comment: Is that possible to connect php with sqlite

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using emulator. It is worked on my browser when the address is localhost:8080

Comment: The only one that was close was the first one, and you ignored your port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also facing the same problem when i worked on localhost. i referred some stackoverflow answer finally i got the solution create a new emulator it works fine in the new emulator.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the emulator,

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/android/dbconnection.php
```

should be the way to go. If that fails as well, check for typos in the address (maybe it's dbConnection.php), take a look at your log cat and also check if you have declared full internet access in your manifest.

Comment: @Aravinth: You might consider explaining, completely and precisely, what "not working" means. Are you able to access this URL from a browser within the emulator?

Comment: @CommonsWare i am able to get the url access within my emulator